# Why we can not use \< to specify \textless

Tags: symbols

Less than and more than can be specified by using `\textless` and `\textgreater`. Why we can not use something like `\<` or  `\>`? Won't it be much easier?

Comment: The commands `\<` and `\>` are used in the `tabbing` environment. But I've never seen a real usage for `\textless` and `\textgreater`: what are you using them for?

Answer (score 8):

if you do not need the `tabbing` environment then you can overwrite the original definitions:

```
\documentclass{report}
\let\<\textless
\let\>\textgreater
\begin{document}

\<foo\> <foo>

\end{document}
```

[image]

With `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` there will be no difference!

Comment: +1 for `[T1]{fontenc}`, then you can simply use `<...>` as you mention.